# How to add common dialog control in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

In a school tutorial document I need to add a common control dialog to my form through project menu then components, but I cannot find the components button. I am using visual basic 2010.

Comment: What you mean by "common control dialog"?

Comment: Check the msdn entry here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.commondialog(v=vs.110).aspx and use the type that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET doesn't use the Common Control Dialog.  What you are looking for is the SaveFileDialog and OpenFileDialog.

Common Controls are what you would use in a COM-based language, like VB6.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commondialog control, VS 2010 had offered five individual controls located under Toolbox -> dialogs. these are ColorDialog, FolderBrowserDialog, FontDialog, OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog. you can use one of these as per your requirement.